# Why are they drawing the matrix differently?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

While I was watching 3Blue1Brown and Eddie Woo videos I realised that they are arrenging the vectors differently. What's happening?

In the videos you will see that for the same matrix \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}

Eddie draws the vector $\vec{AB}$, while 1Brown3Blue gets the vector $\vec{AC}$.

Eddie's [video](https://youtu.be/jh1m0IgiAJI?t=336)

1Brown3Blue's [video](https://youtu.be/Ip3X9LOh2dk?t=514)

What's the reason for this difference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's roughly the same thing as the difference between 1Brown3Blue and 3Blue1Brown. :-)  Anyway, to be a bit serious, 3b1b's video makes a *lot* more sense to me than the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Eddie is treating the matrix as a collection of row vectors stacked on top of each other, while 3B1B is treating it as a collection of column vectors stacked next to each other. If either of them took the transpose of the matrix, they would have the other's diagram. The distinction doesn't matter here, since the determinant of a matrix is the same as the determinant of its transpose.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! When would it matter. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @AlexF.Barnada Although $A$ and $A^\intercal$ are related, they are (frequently) different matrices. It's enough just to calculate that,

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}10\\100\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}100\\20\end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix}200\\10\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}10\\100\end{bmatrix}$$.

At a deeper level, transpose relates to switching between left- and right-multiplication for matrices, in the sense that $(AB)^\intercal = B^\intercal A^\intercal$.

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't express myself properly. I was wondering which one is the usual way to interpret a matrix: having the (x, y) in a row (like Eddie) or in a colum (like 3Blue1Brown). Does it matter?

Comment: @AlexF.Barnada I see. It depends on the situation. As an illustration, you can understand left-multiplication by a matrix $A$ (i.e. $x \mapsto Ax$) as mapping the $n$th basis vector to the $n$th column of $A$ (I think 3b1b explains this in one video). On the other hand, right-multiplication (i.e. $x \mapsto xA$) is mapping the $n$th basis vector to the $n$th *row* of $A$. So in this case, whether $A$ is thought of as a collection of rows or columns depends on which side it's on.